# Unable to set property value VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, createparams

I'm making a custom form for my library

```
Public Class MycustomForm : Inherits Form

    Private Const CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON As Integer = &H200
    Private _CloseBox As Boolean = True

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    <Category("WindowStyle")> _
    <DefaultValue(True)> _
    <Description("This property enables or disables the close button")> _
    Public Property CloseBox As Boolean
        Get
            Return _CloseBox
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If value <> _CloseBox Then
                value = _CloseBox
                Me.RecreateHandle()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim CustomParams As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            If Not _CloseBox Then
                CustomParams.ClassStyle = CustomParams.ClassStyle Or CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON
            End If
            Return CustomParams
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

I created a property to offer developers the possibility of disable the close button

When I test my form in the designer, I changed the `MyForm.Designer`:

```
Partial Class MyForm
    Inherits MycustomForm
```

After, the property has been added, when I try to change the property to `False`, I'm unable to change it, because the property not changes

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a simple mistake.

Change `value = _CloseBox` to `_CloseBox = value`

Answer (score 1):

Note how your property is only used in the CreateParams property getter.  This getter is used only at a very specific time, when the window is *created*.  So if you want your property to have an affect then it is necessary to recreate the window.

That sounds very hard to do, but isn't.  Winforms often has a need to recreate the window on the fly, there are several existing properties that have the same wrinkle.  Like ShowInTaskbar, Opacity, FormBorderStyle, etcetera.  Make your setter look like this:

```
    Set(value As Boolean)
        If value <> _CloseBox Then
            _CloseBox = value
            If Me.IsHandleCreated Then RecreateHandle()
        End If
    End Set
```

The RecreateHandle() method gets the job done.  It flickers a bit btw, inevitably of course.